# eclipse: R.layout.start cannot be or is not a field

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I import an existing project into eclipse, and always encountered this problem. First, it appears the error: R cannot be solved. After import android.R. the error turned to the following methods. "start cannot be or is not a field"

I also checked the gen folder, where contains a R.java file. The file looks good, including the following contents: I also tried to clear the project and rebuilt which didnot work. Does any body have any idea how to solve this? Thanks a lot.

R.java:

```
public static final class layout {
   public static final int kbd=0x7f030000;
   public static final int main=0x7f030001;
   public static final int start=0x7f030002;
}
```

startactivity.java:

```
import android.R;
import android.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    Intent mMain;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);//where error appears**
    }

    public void onStartButtonClick(View v) {
        mMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mMain);
    }
```

Comment: check if there is any problem in any xml... if not then clean rebuild

Comment: Trying hitting save all and doing a clean rebuild.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are importing

```
android.R
```

first remove `android.R and android.R.layout` from import 
and `import R` with your `packagename.R`

for eg. `com.example.R` instead of `android.R`

Comment: Thanks. I solved this problem by deleting all the import lines. And then use ctrl+shift+o to regenerate all the imports.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing Project -> Clean. If that doesn't work it looks like this might have already been answered: [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to clean, but didnot work. The problem was solved by cleaning all imports and regenerate the imports.

Answer (score -1):

To any one who may face the similar problem with me. I found an answer from the link below:
[R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?rq=1)

My problem was solved by:
1. delete all the imports lines.
2. press ctrl+shift+O to manually regenerate all imports.

And then the problem disappeared.

Many thanks for all the comments above.